# Short analysis of AC circuit

Tags: ac, circuit-analysis

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqPjB3.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

For this AC circuit it is known that $$\omega=10^4 \text{rad}/\text{s},L=0.1\text{H}$$ Find capacity of a capacitor, so that the effective value of current \$I\$ doesn't depend on resistance \$R\$. (Phase displacement doesn't change on \$R\$, we already know that).

My reasoning:
For as long as there is a \$U_{ab}\$ voltage, \$R\$ is going to affect current \$I\$, by Kirchhoff's law. If there is no a-b branch it's still going to affect it because \$U\$ is already fixed. So the only way is if there is no resistance on ab branch, that is if \$X_C=0\$, \$C=\infty\$.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Start by looking at resonance.

Comment: Circuit isn't at the resonance. If I assume it, what do I get?

Comment: First part of my comment is meaningless. But I still don't know that I get.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are only two ways that the current through a resistor can be independent of the value of the resistor:

1. The current is zero. This means that the applied voltage must be zero as well. Your solution of making the capacitance infinite (effectively a short circuit) falls into this category.
2. The resistor is connected to a current source. Here's a hint: The circuit as given shows a voltage source connected in series with an inductor, a Thévenin source. It can be redrawn as its Norton equivalent: a current source in parallel with that same inductor. This effectively puts the inductor in parallel with the capacitor and the resistor, too. Is there a way to make sure that all the current from the current source flows through only the resistor?

Answer (score 0):

Find the expression for I, then determine the necessary condition for the coefficient of R to be zero.

Answer (score 0):

In advance, I apologize for not having properly formatted equations. If someone would like to edit and make it look pretty, feel free! 
Otherwise I am going to make it look pretty in the morning.

The simplest way to solve this would be with phasor analysis.

Where:

[image]

and

[image] .

Let's call the voltage difference over the resistor/cap *Vx* and the voltage diff over the inductor *Vy*. We can simply see that:

*I=Vx/R*

*Vy + Vx = U*

*(Vx/Xrc)=(Vy/Xl)*.

Where *Xrc* is the total impedance of the resistor in parallel with the cap.

Solving for *I*, I would then yield a complex (as in imaginary) solution like so:

[image]

Our case of interest is when I no longer depends on R. So when

[image]

As mentioned in the comments, this is something known as the resonance. Usually seen as

[image]

We can rearrange to find that the desired cap value is

[image]